# Bootstrap in ASP.net (Content Page)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add a bootstrap in Asp.net (content page). As soon as I add the link of bootstrap file in one of the content page, it changes the design of my menu created in Master page.

Not sure why as I have only added the bootstrap.css in the content page.

Any one has an idea what could be the reason?

I am trying to use Bootstrap Modal in one of the content page but i don't want my page design , borders to be overrided by bootstrap styles.

Comment: Are you referencing the `bootstrap.css` file after yours? If so you need to add your `style.css` file after `bootrap.css`.

Comment: CSS runs on the client. From a client perspective, there is no difference between a master page and a content page. They're merged together on the server, the resulting HTML is sent to the client.

Comment: Thanks Jackowski & mason. I am referencing to bootstrap.css. I have also added my own custom styles for menu bars and buttons etc already. Irrespective where I move bootstrap.css , style for Master (.css) gets changes. I see some of the margins, padding is also overrided by bootstrap.css file. Please note I have added bootstrap in the beginning of content page and all the custom style sheets are added afterwards.